# Fragment replace() operating differently to remove() + add()

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

According to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace):

> replace() is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all
>   currently added fragments that were added with the same
>   containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same
>   arguments given here.

However my code says otherwise.

My app has 1 activity and multiple fragments. It also has a `BottomNavigationView` with 3 tabs (Options, Game, Leaderboards).

When the `MainActivity` is initialised, 3 fragments are added to the container `FrameLayout` `MainActivity`. Immediately after being added, 2 fragments are hidden which leaves 1 shown on the screen (the opening fragment).

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, firstFragment, "Opening")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout, OptionsFragment(), "Options")
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_layout,LeaderboardsFragment(), "Leaderboards")
    transaction.commitNow()
    val transaction2 = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val options: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Options")!!
    val leaderboards: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Leaderboards")!!
    transaction2.hide(options)
    transaction2.hide(leaderboards)
    transaction2.commitNow()
}
```

From here on out, each fragment that isn't `OptionsFragment()` or `LeaderboardsFragment()` is swapped out via `replace()`.

**OpeningFragment.kt**

```
transaction?.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, playerDetailsFragment, "Add Player")
transaction?.commit()
gameString = "Add Player"
```

`OptionsFragment()` and `LeaderboardsFragment()` are put into view by being selected from the bottom nav, which then hides every other fragment except for the one selected (e.g if Options is selected from bottom nav, then every fragment is hidden except for `OptionsFragment())`.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val fragmentTags = arrayListOf("Opening", "Leaderboards", "Options", "Add Player", "Question", "Location", "Game Over")
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val selectedFragmentTag = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_leaderboards -> "Leaderboards"
        R.id.action_options -> "Options"
        else -> {
            gameString 
        }
    }
    // Selected Fragment
    val selectedFragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(selectedFragmentTag)
    for (fragment_tag in fragmentTags){
        // Hide every Fragment that has been added and isn't the selected Fragment
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment_tag)
        if (fragment != null && fragment != selectedFragment) {
            transaction.hide(fragment)
        }
    }
    transaction.show(selectedFragment!!)
    transaction.commit()
    return true
}
```

This method doesn't work. However - if I use `remove()` and `add()` instead of `replace()`, then it works fine:

**OpeningFragment.kt**

```
    val opening = fragmentManager?.findFragmentByTag("Opening")
    transaction?.remove(opening!!)
    transaction?.add(R.id.fragment_layout, playerDetailsFragment, "Add Player")
    transaction?.commit()
    gameString = "Add Player"
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Just a question - why do you hide fragments instead adding them moment when they're needed?

Comment: Because by hiding and showing I was able to maintain the `View.Visibiliity` state of my `View` elements - something which `add()` didn't save.

Comment: I think you should consider separating preserving some state from view and treat views as rendered models, keeping view states attached to activity or application - check out MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me replace works exactly as docs says.  It removes **all** fragments in given container id and then adds new fragment with specified tag.

Your optional code removes only one fragment that you desire, not all of them, therefore it's not identical to replace function.